# Regression model where N is greater than number of polygons

Tags: spatial-statistics, sar, spdep

[image: My spatial polygons with unique IDs]

I'm trying to construct an analysis where 100 users record data for each polygon in the map below, a total of 17 values per user. Using the values from each polygon, I wanted to generate a model that would predict a continuous independent variable recorded separately.

I was planning to run a SAR, but I have realized while simulating the data that it isn't the right analysis to use since my N is greater than the number of polygons.

I have already created a neighbors weight matrix for the polygon using SPDEP.

I'm not from the world of GIS. I'm currently looking into a mixed model.

Comment: I would point out that, in terms of a spatial or a mixed effects model, you are intentionally introducing a pseudo-replication issue. In a linear model, of whatever flavor, you are violating iid assumptions.